# rails activeadmin member_action form support

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

there has form support for batch_action

```rb
batch_action :flag, form: {
   type: %w[Offensive Spam Other],
   reason: :text,
   notes:  :textarea,
   hide:   :checkbox,
   date:   :datepicker
} do |ids, inputs|
  redirect_to collection_path, notice: [ids, inputs].to_s
end
```

But i need similar form popup when i click a member_action link, how can i archive it?

if i use render view in member_action, it will redirect to new page, no popup. if i use bootstrap modal directly, the style can't be the same with the activeadmin theme.

Answer (score 0):

may be try it add it into flash message with `flash[:notice].now=[ids,inputs].to_s` and then redirect

Comment: if i use member_action, there shouldn't have ids, inputs. And i think flash is not reasonable way.